# enabling the node_option --loader ts-node/esm shows the wrong line number in exception stackTraces

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

Enabling the node_option --loader ts-node/esm shows the wrong line number in exception stackTraces

Here is a minimial github repo reproducing the problem
https://github.com/deltaboukensha/bug-ts-loader

In the npm run test script I enabled ts-mocha --loader ts-node/esm

The stacktraces now show the wrong lines

Disabling the option and the lines point to the correct place

This is a for another company project where I will describe the benefits of using typescript. I would really like to solve these mysterious issues and explain them at least.

test.ts

```
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';

it('throws error but shows the wrong line', async () => {
  const a = 2;
  const b = 4;
  
  const c = a+ b;
  expect(c).to.be.eq(7);
})

// 1) throws error but shows the wrong line:

//       AssertionError: expected 6 to equal 7
//       + expected - actual

//       -6
//       +7
      
//       at /home/delta/dev/bug-ts-mocha/test.ts:17:33 <--- should be line 9
//       at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
//       at /home/delta/dev/bug-ts-mocha/test.ts:8:71
//       at new Promise (<anonymous>)
//       at __awaiter (test.ts:4:12)
//       at Context.<anonymous> (test.ts:13:51)
//       at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "bug-ts-loader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ts-mocha test.ts --loader=ts-node/esm"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*", "./@types/*", "./test/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "@types/*",
      "node_modules/@types/*"
    ],
    "types": ["node", "mocha"]
  },
  "exclude": ["dist"]
}
```

Thanks for any help.

I expect the line-numbers in the stack-trace to point to the correct line in the file